# JSON data changes on every refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax

I got an ajax call which fetches data from a json file. After which i calculate the length of the object and get only the length. Everything is working fine. But on refresh its not displaying the data in the same order

```
//url i get from another file.which is a object hardcoded.
var initialsource = [{ "data": [] }];
var totallength = url.length;
var j = 0; // dummy variable to check whether the data has reached full length;

$.each(url,function(keys,values){   
    console.log(keys);  // get the keys which is mapped to json file location.// 1st console.
    $.get(values, function(jsondata) { // ajax call made to get the data
        console.log(keys); // 2nd console.
        initialsource[0].data.push({ 
            "datasource": keys,
            "values": jsondata[0].xxx.length
        })           
        j++;
        if (j == totallength) {
            //render data to html
        }
    })    
})
```

**For first refresh**

console-1 output

```
Data-1:value-1
Data-2:value-2
Data-3:value-3
Data-4:value-4
```

console-2 output

```
Data-1:value-1
Data-2:value-2
Data-3:value-3
Data-4:value-4
```

**For second refresh**

console-1 output

```
Data-1:value-1
Data-2:value-2
Data-3:value-3
Data-4:value-4
```

console-2 output //changes are happening here

```
Data-2:value-2
Data-1:value-1
Data-3:value-3
Data-4:value-4
```

And on every refresh i get the data order changed. Which is reflected in my html too. If someone could hel

Comment: This is because the `$.get` requests are asynchronous. This means that they are not guaranteed to be returned in the order in which they are sent. If you need to maintain the order, you need to `sort()` the object after the requests have completed.

Comment: You must to use promises or `$.Deferred` object to execute `sort()` when all is finished from retrieve.

Comment: I made the output more detailed. Here the key is Data-1 and the ajax call is value-1. So my assumption is it has nothing to do with asynchronous function. If, async is true, then the Data-1 should be mapped to value-2. But the data and value are mapped correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `$.get` requests are asynchronous. This means that they are not guaranteed to be returned in the order in which they are sent. If you need to maintain the order, you need to `sort()` the object after the requests have completed. Try this:

```
var requests = [];

$.each(url, function(keys, values) {   
    requests.push($.get(values, function(jsondata) {
        initialsource[0].data.push({ 
            "datasource": keys,
            "values": jsondata[0].xxx.length
        });
    }));  
})

$.when.apply(this, requests).done(function() {
    var sortedData = initialsource.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.values < b.values;
    });
    // sortedData is now in length order, use it as required here...
});
```

Comment: I deleted the temporary files and its working fine now. I need a clarification, using sort will set in alphabetical order right. But i dont want it to set in alphabetical order.

Comment: No, it will sort numerically, as the `values` property is a number.

Comment: I edited the output and posted my doubt in the question comment. Can you have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't sort data based on key using jQuery and do operation what you want to do. i have paste code of custom sort please hope do needful for you.

```
jQuery.fn.sort = function() {  
    return this.pushStack( [].sort.apply( this, arguments ), []);  
};  

 function sortLastName(a,b){  
     if (a.l_name == b.l_name){
       return 0;
     }
     return a.l_name> b.l_name ? 1 : -1;  
 };  
  function sortLastNameDesc(a,b){  
     return sortLastName(a,b) * -1;  
 };
var people= [
{
"f_name": "john",
"l_name": "doe",
"sequence": "0",
"title" : "president",
"url" : "google.com",
"color" : "333333",
}]

sorted=$(people).sort(sortLastNameDesc);
```