# Twitch TV JSON API Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So,I am trying to use the twitch API:
https://codepen.io/sterg/pen/yJmzrN 
If you check my codepen page you'll see that each time I refresh the page the status order changes and I can't figure out why is this happening.
Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ur="";
    var tw=["freecodecamp","nightblue3","imaqtpie","bunnyfufuu","mushisgosu","tsm_dyrus","esl_sc2"];
    var j=0;
    for(var i=0;i<tw.length;i++){   
        ur="https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+tw[i];

        $.getJSON(ur,function(json) {

            $(".tst").append(JSON.stringify(json));
            $(".name").append("<li> <a href="+"https://www.twitch.tv/"+tw[j]+">"+tw[j]+"</a><p>"+""+"</p></li>");

            if(json.stream==null){
                $(".stat").append("<li>"+"Offline"+"</li>");

            }
            else{
                $(".stat").append("<li>"+json.stream.game+"</li>"); 

            }
            j++;
    })

    }


});
```

Comment: you can't guarantee the completion order of asynchronous GET's - either refactor your code to do one get at a time, or make it smarter in where it inserts the results

Comment: This question was previously answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723032/json-data-changes-on-every-refresh

Comment: @ScottieCrump Let's not close this as a duplicate.  There are several other serious problems with this code that have been addressed in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` works asynchronously.  The JSON won't be returned until the results come back.  The API can return in different orders than the requests were made, so you have to handle this.

One way to do this is use the promise API, along with `$.when()` to bundle up all requests as one big promise, which will succeed or fail as one whole block.  This also ensures that the response data is returned to your code in the expected order.

Try this:

```
var channelIds = ['freecodecamp', 'nightblue3', 'imaqtpie', 'bunnyfufuu', 'mushisgosu', 'tsm_dyrus', 'esl_sc2'];
$(function () {
  $.when.apply(
    $, 
    $.map(channelIds, function (channelId) {
      return $.getJSON(
        'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + encodeURIComponent(channelId)
      ).then(function (res) {
        return {
          channelId: channelId,
          stream: res.stream
        }
      });
    })
  ).then(function () {
    console.log(arguments);
    var $playersBody = $('table.players tbody');
    $.each(arguments, function (index, data) {
      $playersBody.append(
        $('<tr>').append([
          $('<td>'),
          $('<td>').append(
            $('<a>')
              .text(data.channelId)
              .attr('href', 'https://www.twitch.tv/' + encodeURIComponent(data.channelId))
          ),
          $('<td>').text(data.stream ? data.stream.game : 'Offline')
        ])
      )
    })
  })
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrOxwo

Here, I'm using `$.when.apply()` to use `$.when` with an array, rather than list of parameters.  Next, I'm using `$.map()` to convert the array of channel IDs into an array of promises for each ID.  After that, I have a simple helper function with handles the normal response (`res`), pulls out the relevant stream data, while attaching the channelId for use later on.  (Without this, we would have to go back to the original array to get the ID.  You can do this, but in my opinion, that isn't the best practice.  I'd much prefer to keep the data with the response so that later refactoring is less likely to break something. This is a matter of preference.)

Next, I have a `.then()` handler which takes all of the data and loops through them.  This data is returned as arguments to the function, so I simply use `$.each()` to iterate over each argument rather than having to name them out.

I made some changes in how I'm handling the HTML as well.  You'll note that I'm using `$.text()` and `$.attr()` to set the dynamic values.  This ensures that your HTML is valid (as you're not really using HTML for the dynamic bit at all).  Otherwise, someone might have the username of `<script src="somethingEvil.js"></script>` and it'd run on your page.  This avoids that problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're appending the "Display Name" in the same order every time you refresh, by using the `j` counter variable.

However, you're appending the "Status" as each request returns. Since these HTTP requests are asynchronous, the order in which they are appended to the document will vary each time you reload the page.

If you want the statuses to remain in the same order (matching the order of the Display Names), you'll need to store the response data from each API call as they return, and order it yourself before appending it to the body.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I changed the last `else` condition (the one that prints out the streamed game) as `$(".stat").append("<li>"+jtw[j]+": "+json.stream.game+"</li>");` - it was identical in meaning to what you tried to achieve, yet produced the same error.

**There's a discrepancy in the list you've created and the data you receive.** They are not directly associated.

It is a preferred way to use `$(".stat").append("<li>"+json.stream._links.self+": "+json.stream.game+"</li>");`, you may even get the name of the user with regex or `substr` in the worst case.

As long as you don't run separate loops for uploading the columns "DisplayName" and "Status", you might even be able to separate them, in case you do not desire to write them into the same line, as my example does.

Whatever way you're choosing, in the end, the problem is that  the "Status" column's order of uploading is not identical to the one you're doing in "Status Name".

Answer (score 0):

This code will not preserve the order, but will preserve which array entry is being processed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ur = "";
    var tw = ["freecodecamp", "nightblue3", "imaqtpie", "bunnyfufuu", "mushisgosu", "tsm_dyrus", "esl_sc2"];
    for (var i = 0; i < tw.length; i++) {
        ur = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + tw[i];
        (function(j) {
            $.getJSON(ur, function(json) {
                $(".tst").append(JSON.stringify(json));
                $(".name").append("<li> <a href=" + "https://www.twitch.tv/" + tw[j] + ">" + tw[j] + "</a><p>" + "" + "</p></li>");
                if (json.stream == null) {
                    $(".stat").append("<li>" + "Offline" + "</li>");
                } else {
                    $(".stat").append("<li>" + json.stream.game + "</li>");
                }
            })
        }(i));
    }
});
```

This code will preserve the order fully - the layout needs tweaking though

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ur = "";
    var tw = ["freecodecamp", "nightblue3", "imaqtpie", "bunnyfufuu", "mushisgosu", "tsm_dyrus", "esl_sc2"];
    for (var i = 0; i < tw.length; i++) {
        ur = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + tw[i];
        (function(j) {
            var name = $(".name").append("<li> <a href=" + "https://www.twitch.tv/" + tw[j] + ">" + tw[j] + "</a><p>" + "" + "</p></li>");
            var stat = $(".stat").append("<li></li>")[0].lastElementChild;
            console.log(stat);
            $.getJSON(ur, function(json) {
                $(".tst").append(JSON.stringify(json));
                if (json.stream == null) {
                    $(stat).text("Offline");
                } else {
                    $(stat).text(json.stream.game);
                }
            }).then(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }, function(e) {
                console.error(e);
            });
        }(i));
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code is blindly trusting that the channel names are usable in URLs and HTML.  You should use `encodeURIComponent()`, and `.text()` or `.attr()` as necessary.

Comment: @Brad I can think of 10 other changes to the original code. My answer is directly addressing the issue in the question, not issues that have not even been thought of in the question, or may become an issue with HTML6, or ES2020. Personally, the code I would write for this would be completely different to the code presented in the question, however I posted an answer that takes minimal changes to the original code, and hopefully address the issues in the question fully.

Comment: Sure, **I** get that, but I'm pointing it out in a comment because people copy/paste code from StackOverflow all the time without knowing what they're doing.  At least by leaving a comment, someone might read it and know that they have more work to do.

Comment: I see your point @Brad - I'll try to add such obvious details in the future